# I need to create a file with all hashicorp vault key value pairs data using shell script

Tags: shell, hashicorp-vault

I need to create a file with all hashicorp vault key value pairs data using shell script.

I want to dump all the data from vault to a flat file.

please advice best way to do it.

Thanks in advance
Prudhvi

Answer (score 0):

Just for keys and values you can use my little Perl script 'vault-backup', that also freezes the data using the correct vault commands.

Please note that this does NOT create a full backup of your Vault! There are no methods being backed up, or any other (unlistable) stuff outside the secrets. It's only usable for simple keys and values. It also probably isn't usable for multiline or binary values. You can patch the script to support that, if you like. ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# 
# Usage: vault-backup [<PATH> [stdout]]

use Data::Dumper;
use Storable qw(freeze thaw);

# Set vault environment variables
# Always end with a " && " for the actual command
my $setenv =
    "VAULT_ADDR=https://myvault.somewhere.com:8200 && ".
    "VAULT_CA_PATH=/etc/yourcertificates/ && ";

my $path = $ARGV[0] || "secret/";
if ($path!~/\/$/) {
    $path="$path/";
}
push @list, getData($path);

if ($ARGV[1] eq "stdout") { 
   print Dumper(\@list);
} else {
    my $fn="vault-backup-frozen-".time().".dat";
    open W,">$fn";
    print W freeze(\@list);
    close W;
    print STDERR "Wrote data to $fn\n";
}

sub getData {
    my $path=shift;
    print STDERR "Starting getData($path)\n";
    my @ret=();
    my $command="$setenv vault kv list -tls-skip-verify $path | tail -n+3 ";
    print STDERR "starting command: $command\n";
    my @lines = `$command`;
    chomp @lines;
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        if ($line=~/\/$/) {
            my @result = getData($path.$line);
            if (scalar(@result)>0) {
                # Find deeper results
                push @ret, @result;
            } else {
                # empty final dir, no values
                push @ret, { path => $path.$line };
            }
        } else {
            # Found a key!
            my $command="$setenv vault kv get -tls-skip-verify $path$line";
            print STDERR "starting command: $command\n";
            my $values = `$command`;
            push @ret, {path=>$path.$line, value=>$values};
        }
    }
    return @ret;
}
```

To restore the data, you can use the script below. It handles data only, it does not act on metadata.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Usage: vault-restore <backup-filename>

use Data::Dumper;
use Storable qw(thaw);

my %all_entries;



# Set vault environment variables
# Always end with a " && " for the actual command
my $setenv =
    "VAULT_ADDR=https://myothervault.somewhere.com:8200 && ".
    "VAULT_CA_PATH=/etc/mycertificates/ && ";

# Read the data
my $fn = $ARGV[0] || die("I need a filename with the frozen data");
open F,"<$fn";
my @list = @{ thaw(join("",<F>)) };
close F;

print STDERR "Read ".scalar(@list)." entries.\n";


# Process the data
foreach my $entry (@list) {
    print STDERR "\n# adding entry -> $entry->{path}\n";
    addEntry($entry);
}


foreach my $path (keys %all_entries) {
    my $keyvalues="";
    foreach my $key (keys %{$all_entries{$path}}) {
        my $value=$all_entries{$path}{$key};
        $keyvalues.="'$key=$value' ";
    }
    print STDERR "vault kv put $path $keyvalues\n"; 
    # `$command`; 
}



sub addEntry {
    my $entry=shift;
    my $path = $entry->{'path'};
    if ($entry->{'value'}) {
        my $values = $entry->{value};
        my @list=split("\n", $values);
        my $metadata_engage=0;
        my $data_engage=0;
        foreach my $keyvalue (@list) {
            if ($keyvalue=~/==== Metadata ====/) {
                $metadata_engage=1;
                $data_engage=0;
            } elsif ($keyvalue=~/==== Data ====/) {
                $metadata_engage=0;
                $data_engage=1;
            } elsif ($data_engage) {
                my ($key,$value)=($keyvalue=~/^([^ ]+) +(.*)$/);
                if ($key ne "Key" && $key ne "---") {
#                   print STDERR "key=$key ; value=$value\n";
                    $all_entries{$path}{$key}=$value;
                } else {
                    # print STDERR "-- separator\n"; 
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print STDERR "Found a final but empty path: $path\n";
    }
}
```